# Can't create custom Desktop file in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: .desktop, 18.10

I created a custom desktop file and placed it in `~/.local/share/applications` but it doesn't appear when I show all applications, I then tried to put it in `/usr/share/applications` to no avail.

I can still run it by double click in Ubuntu 18.10, but I can't in Kubuntu 18.10 with the same file (it returned error about invalid desktop file or malformatted).

There's something so wrong here, because I did the same thing hundreds of time before in the previous versions and never did I encouter this problem.

May anyone know anything about this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=3.3.1
Name=Spyder3
GenericName=Spyder3
Comment=The Scientific Python Development Environment - Python 3
Icon=spyder3
TryExec=spyder3
Exec=spyder3 %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/x-python;
Categories=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;
Keywords=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;
StartupNotify=true
```

Edit: I don't know why but after restarting, I can't open it in Ubuntu anymore. It says `There was an error launching the application`. In Kubuntu, it returns

> KDEInit could not launch 'spyder3': Could not open library
>   'libkdeinit5_spyder3'. Cannot load library libkdeinit5_spyder3:
>   (libkdeinit5_spyder3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with spyder installed via anaconda. Just use full path in two lines `TryExec=` and `Exec=`.